# Inyectar Javascript al cambiar de URL en un WebView Android Studio

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Quisiera saber si alguien me pudiera ayudar.
Mi problema es que Estoy abriendo una página web dentro de un web view, ahora esta página tiene un menú de navegación

```
<aside id="left-panel">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="distribuir_cuentas" title="Distribuir Cuentas"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-play"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">Distribuir Cuentas</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="movimientos" title="Movimientos"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-credit-card"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">Movimientos</span></a></li>
      <li><a id="reportar_cuenta" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Reportar Cuenta"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw fa-slack"></i><span class="menu-item-parent">Reportar fallo cuenta</span></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</aside>
```

En la Página o URL de distribuir cuentas, hay una tabla que no se puede visualizar bien una tabla porque le falta un estilo overflow-x, este es el código que he probado para ello:

```
document.getElementById('id_tabla').style.overflowX = 'auto'; 
document.getElementById('id_tabla').style.whiteSpace = 'nowrap';
```

Quisiera saber si este Javascript lo puedo añadir y de que manera al dar click en el menu de "Distribuir Cuentas".
Aclaro, esta página no es mía, por eso quiero modificarla directamente desde Javascript al redireccionar a la otra interfaz.

Agradezco sus ayudas.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobreescribir el método [onPageFinished()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) de [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient)
 para poder obtener la nueva url:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        // Injecta aquí!
    }
});
```

Luego puedes inyectar código javascript de esta manera:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {"
+ codigoJS + // codigoJS es el código javascript como string
"})()");
```

Espero te funcione. Saludos!

Referencias:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868599/unable-to-get-current-url-on-click-event-of-webview-in-android
- https://medium.com/@filipe.batista/inject-javascript-into-webview-2b702a2a029f

Comment: Pero como inyectaría : document.getElementById('id_tabla').style.overflowX = 'auto';

Comment: Como dije en la respuesta, es simplemente un string: 
`String codigoJS = "document.getElementById('id_tabla').style.overflowX = 'auto';"`

Comment: Edité la respuesta para que sea más clara, también lee los comentarios de los códigos.

Answer (score 0):

```
function newwin(inject="Inject Code",target,options=0){
target ? target : this.target    
this.open(`javascript:void(0);\``+inject+`\``,this.target,options);
this.document.close()  
}

newwin("helo","_blank","0,0,0,0")


O directamente desde un enlace

<a href="javascript:void(0);`code in about:blank`"> link </a>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).